# How to work with functions that set both a count and populate an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vulkan

The Vulkan API function [vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties.html) contains a count address and array address as parameters. For this question, the first parameter may be ignored. Function signature below:

```
VkResult vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(
    const char*                                 pLayerName,
    uint32_t*                                   pPropertyCount,
    VkExtensionProperties*                      pProperties);
```

The behaviour of `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties` as defined by the documentation (linked above):

If the `pProperties` argument is `nullptr`, the `pPropertyCount` argument is set to the number of available structs.

Otherwise, `pPropertyCount` should reflect the size of the `pProperties` array that is passed and the array gets populated. If the array is too small, the first `pPropertyCount` items are returned (and the function returns an error code).

I imagine this is a somewhat common design choice in C++ (or at least in the Vulkan API), otherwise I wouldn't stumble upon it in my first few hours playing around with Vulkan, *so my question (which I ask below) can probably be answered more generally*, but a Vulkan-specific answer is also welcome.

---

I want to retrieve all the structs that this function provides.

The [Vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Instance#page_Checking_for_extension_support) I was (loosely) following specifies I should implement this using the following 'algorithm':

1. Retrieve the element count **with a first call**
2. Allocate some array or data structure
3. Populate the array **with a second call**

In code that would look something like this (the tutorial uses a vector and passes it's reserved array):

```
uint32_t count = 0;
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &count, nullptr); // only retrieve count
VkExtensionProperties* list = new VkExtensionProperties[count];
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &count, list); // now populate the array
// after use
delete[] list;
```

However, this requires calling the Vulkan API function twice. It feels to me this was not the intention of the designers of the Vulkan API. Are there more optimal ways to retrieve the list of structs?

The [Vulkan documentation page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties.html) states that the number of available structs may differ between successive calls if the API state changes.

Comment: There are other functions which require the same approach - the first call fills the number of elements returned by the second, actual call. And this is a design choice. But mind that Vulkan-Hpp, a C++ wrapper for Vulkan, simplifies this: the first (and only) call returns a filled std::vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I imagine this is a somewhat common design choice in C++

I would say it's a common [API] design choice in *C*.  C++ has other / better ways to do this (perhaps returning a `std::vector` would be appropriate here).

> However, this requires calling the Vulkan API function twice. It feels to me this was not the intention of the designers of the Vulkan API.

Seems to me that that is *exactly* the intention, else the tutorial wouldn't say so!  How else would you do it?  Anyway, I wouldn't worry about it too much.  If doing that was expensive, they wouldn't do it that way.

> The Vulkan documentation page states that the number of available structs may differ between successive calls if the API state changes.

This sounds unlikely to happen in practice, just from glancing at that link, but if you get `VK_INCOMPLETE` back you can just throw the results away and start over.

> In code that would look something like this...

That looks fine - in C - but in C++ what the tutorial is doing (using a vector and passing its reserved array) would be my choice.  I imagine that the Vulkan API is deliberately written in C so that both C and C++ programs can make use of it.

---

**Edit**, to address the OP's question in the comments about why Vulkan chose this style of API:

Well, it's very practical.  Putting aside what I find a rather irrelevant detail about whether it should be one function or two (who cares, really?), the better question is who should allocate the necessary memory to hold the results and why.

There are two basic approaches:

1. The caller allocates the required memory and then takes responsibility for freeing it when it is done with it.
2. The library allocates the required memory and provides an additional (probably generic) function to free it when the caller is done with it.

Method 1 is widely used in the Win32 API, and it has the advantage that the example you quoted from the tutorial, i.e. this (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);
std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> extensions(extensionCount);
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, extensions.data());
```

is possible.  If the library allocates the memory, this is more awkward.

Method 2 means that you would only need to call `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties()` once, since it can allocate whatever amount of memory it needs and return it to you.

So, method 1 is more flexible and method 2 is certainly more convenient and perhaps a bit more efficient (how much more efficient depends entirely on what lies behind the API.

**Please note**: it is not a wise choice to have the library allocate the memory and the caller free it.  Doing that is the road to ruin (they may well be using different heaps, for example, imagine the mess *that* would make).

**Suggestion**: wrap the bits of Vulkan you plan to use behind a nice, friendly C++ API that returns results like this in the most appropriate container.  If you plan to make any serious use of it, you'll be glad you did.

**Update**: Oh, someone did that already, see @Ekzuzy's comment above.  Nice.

Comment: @Jochem Just a heads-up - polished up my answer, you might like to glance through it again.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! Do you know the reason why C-style API design uses this pattern? To me, it seems like it violates the single responsibility principle; the function is both concerned with delivering data and counting it. At the very least, a `*-Count` (suffix) function could be exposed with the sole purpose of reporting the number of elements.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers I think this design choice was made to lower the number of (unnecessary) functions exposed by the API. As for the responsibility - it is developer's responsibility to acquire the required memory space (number of elements) and to allocate this memory. Besides, in the `pPropertyCount` argument this function always returns the number of elements stored in the last argument (it overwrites it, so for example You know how many elements were stored when Your actual array is bigger). So it is a reasonable approach to use this same behavior, to get the total number of elements.

Comment: @Jochem Updated my answer to address your question above.

Comment: "If doing that was expensive, they wouldn't do it that way." This is a really bad assumption. I have profiled a number of Vulkan calls using this API design (e.g. `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties`) and both calls take the same amount of time (which is sometimes tens or hundreds of milliseconds). It's a pretty awful API choice.